# $3$ first year, $3$ second year and $4$ third year students who have agreed to help.How many different ways can they arrive at the common room?…

Tags: combinatorics

Have a pretty standard combinatorics question that is causing me some confusion:

> During a School's Open Day there are $3$ first year, $3$ second year and $4$ third
> year students who have agreed to help. How many different ways can they arrive at the common room in the morning for their briefing

> (**a**) assuming they all arrive at random?
> (**b**) if the first person to enter the room is a first year student, and the last person to enter the room is a third year student?
> (**c**) if all of the third year students arrive in sequence, one after another?

Unsure if (**a**) is $\frac{10!}{3!3!4!}$ or simply just 10!

Also unsure of how to approach (**b**) and (**c**)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The students are obviously "distinct", so it's $10!$ for (a): all permutations yield a different arrival order.

For (b), there are $3$ choices for the first, $4$ for the last, and $8!$ for the remaining, so $3\times4\times8!$.

(c) is slightly more tricky: first, there are $4!$ possibilities for the third year students. And obviously $6!$ for the others (just pretend you remove the sequence of 3rd year students from the arrival order). Now, for each of the $6!$ possibilities, the sequence of 3rd year students can be anywhere among the others, and there are $7$ possibilities (before every one else, after the first, ... or after everyone else). So $7\times4!\times6!$.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot